# How to query for birthdays in Spring data mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am unable to arrive a query to get all records who's birthday is today. I need match only day and month

I tried many combinations including $match and $expr. Nothing seems to be working.

```
public interface GenericPolicyRepository extends MongoRepository<GenericPolicy, String> {
    @Query("{ 'agentId': ?0 , '$expr': { '$eq': [{ '$month': '$dateOfBirth' }, ?1]}, '$expr': { '$eq': [{ '$dayOfMonth': '$dateOfBirth' }, ?2]}}")
    public List<GenericPolicy> findAllBirthDaysByAgent(String agentId, String month, String day);
}
```

//Generic policy class

```
@Document("Policy")
public class GenericPolicy {  
    @Id
    private String policyId;

    private String agentId;
    private String insuredUserId;
    private String status;
    private Date policyStartDate;
    private Date policyEndDate;
    private String paymentReferenceNumber;
    private BigInteger premium;
    private Date dateofSubmission;
    private String submissionStatus;
    private InsuredDetails insuredDetails;
}
```

//insure details

```
 public class InsuredDetails {

        @NotNull
        private String nationality;
        @NotNull
        private String fullName;
        @NotNull
        private String gender;
        @NotNull
        private Date dateOfBirth;
        @NotNull
        private String identityType;
        @NotNull
        private String identityNumber;
        @NotNull
        @Email
        private String emailaddress;
        @NotNull
        @Size(max = 10,min = 10)
        private String mobileNumber;
        @NotNull
        private String addressLine1;
        @NotNull
        private String addressLine2;
        @NotNull
        private String postCode;
    }
```

Comment: Hi can you display "GenericPolicy" Class definition??

Comment: @Nithin I added it. It interface.

Comment: Yea "GenericPolicyRepository" entity is an interface but I am asking about your "GenericPolicy.class" file.

Comment: @Nithin. sorry, I added all the required details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the classes mentioned, given document has a nested document **insuredDetails** (assumed to be the same name in db as well). This field has the **dateOfBirth** field. Keeping this fact in mind, query can be written as follows.

```
public interface GenericPolicyRepository extends MongoRepository<GenericPolicy, String> {
    @Query("{'agentId': ?0 , '$expr': {'$and': [{'$eq': [{'$dayOfMonth': '$insuredDetails.dateOfBirth'}, {'$dayOfMonth': ?1}]}, {'$eq': [{'$month': '$insuredDetails.dateOfBirth'}, {'month': ?1}]}]}}")
    public List<GenericPolicy> findAllBirthDaysByAgent(String agentId, Date birthDate);
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class GenericPolicyServiceImpl implements GenericPolicyService {

    @Autowired
    GenericPolicyRepository genericPolicyRepository;

    public List<GenericPolicy> getAllBirthDaysByAgent(String agentId, String month, String day){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = Integer.parseInt(month);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(day);
        c.set(0, month, day, 0, 0);
        Date birthDate = c.getTime();
        genericPolicyRepository.findAllBirthDaysByAgent(agentId, birthDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It says unknown top level operation expr

Comment: It is because of version. I am actually testing it on flapdoodle.

Comment: Getting syntax  error with this one too.
"{'agentId': ?0 , '$redact': { "
   + "'$cond': [ "
    + "'$and': ["
     + "{'$eq': [{'$dayOfMonth': '$insuredDetails.dateOfBirth'}, {'$dayOfMonth': ?1}]},"
     + "{'$eq': [{'$month': '$insuredDetails.dateOfBirth'}, {'month': ?1}]}"
     + "]"
    + "],"
   + "'$$KEEP','$$PRUNE'}"
  + "}"

Answer (score 1):

try below in query where dateOfBirth is the key saved in your collection here we match day of month and month of current date with one stored in collection

```
  {
            $expr: {
                        "$and": [
                            {"$eq": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$dateOfBirth"}, {"$dayOfMonth": new Date()}]},
                            {"$eq": [{"$month": "$dateOfBirth"}, {"$month": new Date()}]}
                        ]
                    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but this works directly on mongo cli. Getting lot of json parser exceptions. I am trying to make it work.